# How to ajax update an item in the footer of a PrimeFaces dataTable?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, accessibility

This is a visual of the table I have:

```
+---------+------------+-------------------+
| Header1 |  Header2   | Header3           |
+---------+------------+-------------------+
| Row A   |  Input A   | Calc'ed output A  |
| Row B   |  Input B   | Calc'ed output B  |
| etc..   |  etc..     |  etc..            |
+---------+------------+-------------------+
|    Total:          Total calc'ed output  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

And the stripped-down code:

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{myBean.someList}"
    var="currentItem">

    <p:column headerText="Header1">
        <h:outputText value="#{currentItem.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Header2">
        <pe:inputNumber value="#{currentItem.inputVal}">
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.changeListener}"
                update="outputVal outputTotal" />
        </pe:inputNumber>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Header3">
        <h:outputText id="outputVal" value="#{currentItem.outputVal}" />
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        Total:
        <h:outputText id="outputTotal" value="#{myBean.total}" />
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

The `myBean.someList` is an `ArrayList<SomeOtherBean>` with one String and two Integers, with just getters and setters.  The `myBean.changeListener` calculates the second Integer from the first for the given row, and also the total for all rows.

So, when I type in one of the inputs then focus out, the listener is called and the calculation done, but on screen, the value in the third column changes, but the total stubbornly remains zero.  I'm fairly sure this has something to do with PrimeFaces appending the row index to the generated id's of each input and output, but I can't figure out how to get to the output in the footer (whose generated id is `mainForm:myTable:0:outputTotal`).

Now, I could just update the parent table. However whenever the input to receive focus is part of the update target, the focus is lost, and I am under extremely strict accessibility rules that this table *must* be keyboard friendly (type a number, tab, type a number, tab, etc...)

I have tried:

- update=":outputTotal" (gave exception Cannot find component with identifier...)
- update="myTable:0:outputTota (same exception)
- update="myTable:outputTotal" (no update, total stays zero)
- wrap the text in a panelGroup and update that (no update)

(PrimeFaces 3.5.0 with MyFaces unknown version)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't really update the values of the table from within the table. However, you can use `p:remoteCommand` to achieve this. Also, I would probably use the cellEdit event on the whole table (instead of a single `p:ajax` on your `pe:inputNumber`). The overall result would be:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshFooter" update=":formName:outputTotal"/>
...
<p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{myBean.someList}" var="currentItem">

    <p:column headerText="Header1">
        <h:outputText value="#{currentItem.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Header2">
        <pe:inputNumber value="#{currentItem.inputVal}">
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.changeListener}" process="@this"
                oncomplete="refreshFooter();" update="outputVal"/>
        </pe:inputNumber>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Header3">
        <h:outputText id="outputVal" value="#{currentItem.outputVal}" />
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        Total:
        <h:outputText id="outputTotal" value="#{myBean.total}" />
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

Please note that you *might need* to add `partialSubmit="true"` to the `p:ajax`, this way you only submit the component's data. If you like the cellEdit event idea, you need to make the dataTable editable, and add the following in your `p:dataTable`, and get rid of the `p:ajax` inside your `pe:inputNumber`

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" partialSubmit="true" listener="#{myBean.onCellEdit}" 
    process="@this" oncomplete="refreshFooter();"/>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

### Update PrimeFaces

This issue was finally fixed in PrimeFaces 11, or PrimeFaces Elite 8.0.8 / 10.0.1. With PrimeFaces 11+ you can use `partialUpdate="false"` on the data table. Downside of this fix is that it will also update the headers (and filters), so it might update the filter input for you while you are typing. You could set a `delay` on the filter event to improve on this, but the effect won't be gone, only less noticeable.

See:

- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1178
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7165
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/7157

### `PrimeFaces.ab` instead of `p:remoteCommand`

If you don't want to create `p:remoteCommand`s to update components on a data table `filter` event (well, I don't), you could use:

```html
<p:ajax event="filter"
        oncomplete="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'#{component.clientId}',process:'@none',update:'componentToUpdate'})"/>
```

True, this looks a bit messy, but you can create a custom EL function to reduce this to:

```html
<p:ajax event="filter"
        oncomplete="#{my:ajaxUpdate('componentToUpdate')}"/>
```