# update datatable footer primefaces (facet or columnGroup)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to make a footer in dataTable and I need to update when the values inside the DT changes.

The problem is that ajax update simply don't occurs.

I've tried two ways:

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="dataTableAvaliacao" var="aluno"
    value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.alunos}">
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText id="inputNota"
            value="#{aluno.getNota(avaliacao.property).vlNotaString}">

            <p:ajax event="change"
                update=":form:dataTableAvaliacao:mediaAluno, :form:dataTableAvaliacao:mediaAvaliacao" />
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>             

    <p:columnGroup type="footer" id="mediaAvaliacao">

        <p:row>
            <p:column
                 footerText="Nota média da avaliação" />
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <ui:repeat value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.colunasAvaliacoes}"
                var="avaliacao">
                <p:column id="colunaMedia" 
                    footerText="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.getMediaAvaliacao(avaliacao.property)}"/>

            </ui:repeat>
        </p:row>                        
    </p:columnGroup>
<p:dataTable>
```

The update doesn't occurs...

second way (based on this answer on SO: [How to ajax update an item in the footer of a PrimeFaces dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452834/how-to-ajax-update-an-item-in-the-footer-of-a-primefaces-datatable)):

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshFooter" update=":form:dataTableAvaliacao:outputMediaAvaliacao"/>
<p:dataTable 
    id="dataTableAvaliacao" var="aluno"
    value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.alunos}">

    <p:column>
        <p:inputText id="inputNota"
            value="#{aluno.getNota(avaliacao.property).vlNotaString}">

            <p:ajax event="change"
                update=":form:dataTableAvaliacao:mediaAluno" oncomplete="refreshFooter();" />

        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>             
<p:dataTable>           

<f:facet name="footer">
    <h:outputText colspan="1" value="Nota média da avaliação:"/>

    <ui:repeat value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.colunasAvaliacoes}"
        var="avaliacao">

        <h:outputText id="outputMediaAvaliacao"
            value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.getMediaAvaliacao(avaliacao.property)}" 
    </ui:repeat>
</f:facet>
```

I've also tried

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshFooter" update=":form:outputMediaAvaliacao"/>
```

If I put

```
<p:ajax event="change"
                update=":form:dataTableAvaliacao:mediaAluno, :form:dataTableAvaliacao" />
```

in the first way, it works, but I don't wanna update all dataTable every time.

What I'm doing wrong? is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring on **2nd way** from your question that you based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452834/how-to-ajax-update-an-item-in-the-footer-of-a-primefaces-datatable)...

actually **it is possible** to update `p:dataTable` footer (even from within table itself)...but with one modification of your code.

**Reason** why your implementation **does not work** is that you did not take into account that `<h:outputText id="outputMediaAvaliacao"../>` is wrapped with `ui:repeat`.

In that case, `p:remoteCommand` is not able to find `h:outputText` component ID defined in `update` attribute because that ID **does not exist** in [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp):

`ui:repeat` is actually *copying* `h:outputText` as many times as list from `value` attribute is long and appending **all** parent IDs to newly created native HTML components

```
<span id="form:dataTableAvaliacao:avaliacao:0:outputMediaAvaliacao">...</span>
<span id="form:dataTableAvaliacao:avaliacao:1:outputMediaAvaliacao">...</span>
<span id="form:dataTableAvaliacao:avaliacao:2:outputMediaAvaliacao">...</span>
...
```

(you can see the same using [DOM inspector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Inspector) of your favorite browser)

**SOLUTION**

After you learn and understand all facts stated above (like I did :) ), solution is quite simple:

wrap `ui:repeat` with some parent element and assign ID to parent element. For example like this

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    <h:outputText value="Nota média da avaliação:"/>

    <h:panelGroup id="footerPanel">
        <ui:repeat value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.colunasAvaliacoes}"
                   var="avaliacao" id="avaliacao">
             <h:outputText id="outputMediaAvaliacao" value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.getMediaAvaliacao(avaliacao.property)}" />
        </ui:repeat>
     </h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
```

and modify `p:ajax` of `p:inputText` to update newly created element after text is changed

```
<p:ajax event="change" update=":form:dataTableAvaliacao:footerPanel" />
```

On this way all **children** elements of `h:panelGroup` will be updated (meaning only footer will be updated and not entire table).

And now, after you solved updating, you can focus on designing of all UI elements under h:panelGroup to make them fit your requirements.