# Show filter result size in footer of p:dataTable

Tags: primefaces, datatable, primefaces-datatable

I am using a datatable of PrimeFaces with a global filter.
When I enter a filter, I want to refresh the number of rows in the filtered list displayed, but it does not work: update is triggered before `filter()`

Thanks for your help.

Here is my code:

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="widgetColPlanCompteM61"
     filteredValue="#{planCompteM61ManagerBean.listeFiltre}" ...

<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputLabel value="Plan de compte M61"/>
    <p:inputText id="globalFilter">
       <p:ajax event="keyup"  
               oncomplete="PF('widgetColPlanCompteM61').filter()"
               update="idNbLignes"/>
    </p:inputText>
</f:facet>

<f:facet name="footer">
    <h:outputText id="idNbLignes" value="#{planCompteM61ManagerBean.listeFiltre.size()}"/>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: Tried `onstart` instead of `oncomplete`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ajax update an item in the footer of a PrimeFaces dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452834/how-to-ajax-update-an-item-in-the-footer-of-a-primefaces-datatable)